# When to validate your data?

Tags: dataset, validation

I have simulated a scenario under ideal conditions. This simulation was done using the Friis equation to determine the power received by a RFID tag for a particular frequency, distance, power of the transmitter, etc.

Do I need to validate this data against prior articles that uses this equation and got their own data under thier own scenarios?

To me it doesn't make sense to validate data that is firstly under ideal conditions because they will be no change in the output. Secondly if you using a first principle approach and so are other articles then naturally you will come to the same conclusion, so it is taken that your data is valid due to it been under ideal conditions and you using first principles methods to obtain your data. So there's no need to validate it because everyone would produce the same data.

Answer (score 1):

It can never hurt to have another source. Bugs happen, and your function may not have implemented your reference properly.

It’s not a requirement for outsiders so much as to assure yourself you’re not about to base a study on erroneous data.